# An strange error when debug my project what can I do?

Tags: flutter

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.

> Multiple task action failures occurred:
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
> > The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
> dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
> is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
> Dependency: androidx.window:window-java:1.0.0-beta04.
> AAR metadata file: C:\Users\moham.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\625039eaad011f884ddd84f857a44b7f\jetified-window-java-1.0.0-beta04\META-INF\com\android\build\gradle\aar-metadata.properties.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
> > The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
> dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
> is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
> Dependency: androidx.window:window:1.0.0-beta04.
> AAR metadata file: C:\Users\moham.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\a78fdf90e4c1f8464b19895cfb365f3f\jetified-window-1.0.0-beta04\META-INF\com\android\build\gradle\aar-metadata.properties.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJpyb.png)

Comment: have your tried updating your dependencies (androidx.window)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a gradle configuration error. It says that you ave configured a min SDK version of 31 has you have a gradle version that can't compile other version 30.

Two choice are possible, change min SDK configuration or update Gradle.

Answer (score 1):

The error is describe here: `The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a dependency's AAR metadata [...] is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).`

So you need to downgrade the minCompileSdk in your Gradle configuration files (build.gradle).

```dart
android {
    compileSdkVersion 30 // <-- This need to be higher than (see below)

    // Stuff here.
    
    defaultConfig {
        // ...
        minSdkVersion 19 // <-- This.
        // ...
    }
}
```